# OSX Terminal - Change Application Focus

Tags: macos, terminal, focus

Is there a way using command line to change the focus to a specific application? If so, do I need the process id or what?

My goal is to run a process that compiles files, and then focuses on the browser window once the files have finished compiling.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this could be done quite easily with `open -a`.  Opening an already-open application brings it to the forefront.  The `-a` option allows you to specify the application you want, so pick your favorite:

```
open -a Google\ Chrome
open -a Safari
open -a Firefox
```

Comment: is there a way to set this as default?

Comment: @Michael You can set an alias in whatever you're sourcing (`.bashrc`, for example) so `alias open='open -a '` should work.  I use `alias firefox='open -a firefox '`, and so on.

Comment: FWIW, this no longer works for me with MacOS Monterey 12.1

Answer (score 13):

Another option is `osascript -e 'activate application "Google Chrome"'`.